# Theme in magento PHP

Tags: php, magento

I have a rather simple question.

I want to install a new magento theme. In the documentation it says to overwrite the default 'app' and 'skin' folders with the theme's 'app' and 'skin' folders.

"8. Upload the "app" and "skin" folders from the template themeXX folder to your Magento root folder (accept the replacement)"

However, when I am doing that, it prompts me to download magento again thru the magento installation wizard.

To me, it sounds more reasonable to just copy the contents of the 'app' and 'skin' folders of the new theme into the default 'app' and 'skin' folders of the magento framework as they contain some other folders that probably should remain intact.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below url help for create new theme

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-in-magento/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package

hope this help you